# Why do these animation delays nearly never work

Tags: css, animation, webkit

First I'll say that I have next to no CSS skills (slowly trying to fix that) so if its something obvious I do apologize.

In the following animation I have a bunch of delays, one for each letter.
If all goes well you end up with a nice wavey effect, problem is it hardly ever does.
If you keep refreshing sooner or later you'll see it....for me its more often than not the P and A, they end up going up and down at the same rate (there was no delay).
Any advice on how to get this to work sure would be appreciated.

http://jsbin.com/IkuR/1/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Trash</title>


<style id="jsbin-css">
.wavey li:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.wavey li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.wavey li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.wavey li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
.wavey li:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
.wavey li:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.1s;
}
.wavey li:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.3s;
}
.wavey li:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
.wavey li:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.7s;
}
.wavey li {
  width:41px;
  font-size:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  -webkit-animation: upndown 3s infinite;
}

.wavey {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  line-height:69px; 
  color:white;
  font-family: "pixel";
  font-size: 0;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  border:0px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes upndown {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  } 
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
}


html {
  background-color:#000;
  font-size: 0;

}
body { 
  font-size: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;

}

</style>

</head>
<body>

    <ul class="wavey">
        <li>P</li>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>E</li>
        <li>z</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>d</li>
        <li>K</li>
        <li>.</li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For me the problem is that the JSBin site hardly ever works. It just sits there grinding its pepper mill and nothing ever comes out.

Comment: @DJDavid98 Try loading it a few times and see if it keeps playing nice, it doesnt always fail for me either....sure hope this isnt a "just me" problem, their near impossible to fix ;)

Comment: @MrLister Have you ever looked at the console to see if theres any errors?  I LOVE JS Bin, shame if you cant use it.  If you do see any errors tell me what they are and I might be able to help.

Comment: What browser are you using?  I ran it a dozen times in Safari and it worked each time.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird Dam, this is going to be a "just me" thing ;) Im using Chrome 30.0.1599.14 dev-m

Comment: Tried it on Chrome 29.0.1547.57 and it worked for me.  Sorry :(

Comment: @BarbaraLaird Thanks heaps for looking anywayz :)  My comp/windows is a little screwy so maybe its just that....was really hoping it wasnt tho, but by the look of the comments it just may be.

Comment: Please, please specify the unprefixed transform and aninmation properties along with `-webkit-`prefixed ones. Firefox and  IE10+ support the most part of transforms and animations, too. Also, `-webkit-` stuff is not a part of standard CSS, it's just one of the early experimental implementations.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn So sorry, didn't think of that.  Next time I have a CSS question which uses prefixed stuff Ill use the prefixFree script in my JS Bin example, would that be acceptable?

Comment: @PAEz, I think that would be totally OK:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a solution for myself :)
If this happens to anyone else try using negative values for the delay, this seems to be working great.
To quote the MDN....

> Specifying a negative value for the animation delay causes the
>   animation to begin executing immediately. However, it will appear to
>   have begun executing partway through its cycle. For example, if you
>   specify -1s as the animation delay time, the animation will begin
>   immediately but will start 1 second into the animation sequence.

Fixed code....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Trash</title>


<style id="jsbin-css">
.wavey li:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.1s;
}
.wavey li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.3s;
}
.wavey li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.5s;
}
.wavey li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.7s;
}
.wavey li:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
}
.wavey li:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
}
.wavey li:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.3s;
}
.wavey li:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.5s;
}
.wavey li:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.7s;
}
.wavey li {
  width:41px;
  font-size:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  -webkit-animation: upndown 3s infinite;
}

.wavey {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  line-height:69px; 
  color:white;
  font-family: "pixel";
  font-size: 0;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  border:0px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes upndown {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  } 
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
}


html {
  background-color:#000;
  font-size: 0;

}
body { 
  font-size: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;

}

</style>

</head>
<body>

    <ul class="wavey">
        <li>P</li>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>E</li>
        <li>z</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>d</li>
        <li>K</li>
        <li>.</li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```